# Send Message to module in different tab in DotNetNuke

Tags: c#, asp.net, dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-module

I want to create a module that can send a message to another module in different tab. I don't know the target tab Id but I know the target module name.

Is there any way to do such a thing? Does Dot net nuke support messaging?

Answer (score 1):

DNN supports the  IModuleCommunicator and IModuleListener interfaces.  These are for modules on the same page(tab).

Since each request accesses only one page at a time, modules on a different tab will not reliably be loaded and executing at any given time.  Since you can't predict when or even if the other tab will be loaded, the best approach is to persist your message somewhere (database/a file/a message queue etc.) and build the other module to look for messages when it runs.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer.So I should save my message in db/file and the other module load it but how navigate to that page? I don't know which page contains that module.

Comment: @zohreh, if you want to send a user to a different page, you must know what page you want to send them too.  You can lookup all the pages that a particular module is on in via the tabmodules data, but you are still in a bind if the module is on more than one page.  Once you know that page to send them too, a simple Response.Redirect(NavigateUrl(<page params here>)) will do the trick.